# SetOnItemClickListener on ListView of custom object not working?

Tags: java, android

I define this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Content_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_pencil" />  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I want to add 3 items of this layout to a list view. They are displayed fine but when I click on each item. The listener doesn't seem to be invoked.

Here's the implementation inside main activity and the class "item_adapter" which extends ArrayAdapter:

Main_activity:

```
package com.example.selectedlist;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    ListView list;
    int selected;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
        arr.add("ABC");
        arr.add("MGH");
        arr.add("EFG");

        selected = 0;
        list = findViewById(R.id.my_list);
        item_adapter adapter = new item_adapter(this, arr);

        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                TextView txt = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.Content_txt);
            txt.setText("dasd");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

item_adapter:

```
package com.example.selectedlist;

import android.animation.LayoutTransition; import android.content.Context; import android.view.LayoutInflater; import android.view.View; import android.view.ViewGroup; import android.widget.ArrayAdapter; import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull; import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.ArrayList; import java.util.List;

public class item_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    Context main_context;
    List<String> data;

    public item_adapter(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull List<String> objects)
    {
        super(context, R.layout.edit_layout, objects);
        main_context = context;
        data = objects;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent)
    {
        String str = getItem(position);

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(main_context).inflate(R.layout.edit_layout, parent, false);
        TextView txt = view.findViewById(R.id.Content_txt);
        txt.setText(str);

        return view;
    } }
```

Nothing happens when I click on each item. The TextView in the layout is supposed to be changed as shown in the code. Any ideas on this ?

Comment: Hi, I'm not really familiar with listview an ClickListener, but I would set it in item_adapter getView method

Comment: @GGKstandsforUkraine Thank you :D. it's my B approach for this problem.  It seems strange if we can't implement directly in setOnItemClickListener().

Comment: no its not, because you set the listner on the listview, I believe that you must set it on the item. thats where you really want to have it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the method setFocusable of the ImageButton for the listener to work.

```
ImageButton Edit_btn = view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
Edit_btn.setFocusable(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use below code

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                TextView txt = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.Content_txt);
                txt.setText("dasd");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you! Currently on my phone so I'll try that later but why does your code work but mine doesn't

Comment: Because you are getting whole parent view inside on item click but you are thinking you are getting only textview that's why it is not updating textview. Please accept the answer if it is working fine

Comment: @Submit Kuhmar. I posted wrong code. Sorry. I'll update it. But your code 100% not working